# What's the significance of the photo shoot in the opening credits?

Tags: analysis, credits, army-of-the-dead

During the opening credits of *Army of the Dead* (2021), a photo shoot of characters is shown:

[image] [image]

What's the significance of this photo shoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is to establish a basis for what the characters were like/ who they were before the outbreak and the transformations they've gone through before the start of the movie.

Since a common idea in disaster movies is about how people change in response to an adverse change in environment, I think that this movie was trying to reinforce that the characters were once 'normal' and we are viewing a transformed version of them, with these photos showing the 'before'. I think the fact that the present version of these characters are holding the photos reinforces this comparison.